# Getting a string depending on specific input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get a string depending on the input the user chooses. For example, If the user inputs s1, I want a function that can translates s1 to Alabama and put that in h3 tags. The only way I can think of to do this is with switch statements or if/else statements but since their are over 50 states, I think there is a more practical way to do this? I believe it's something like a text file in this format:

```
s1: Alabama
s2: Alaska
s3: Arizona
```

I didn't know what terms to use to search for my issue, but I am sure this has been asked before somewhere. If anyone can point me in the right direction, I would really appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: A dictionary/map mapping the I output string to the state name would likely be the most idiomatic way of achieving this. Basically the same idea as a switch of if tree, but usually much neater.

Comment: oh yes, a map is what i was looking for. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic way of doing this is using a Map that maps the input string to the state name:

```
var stateMap =
    {"s1" : Alabama
     "s2": Alaska
      ...};
```

Then use it like:

```
var stateMap = stateMap[input];
```

---

If the input is always in the form of "s#", you could also just cut the "s" off the front, parse the remaining number, then use that number to index a list of state names.